# Geodesic speed not working

Tags: differential-geometry

From what I know the geodesic speed is equal to unity. I've made this program to plot   geodesics along a surface. 
The surface is embedded in 3d Euclidean flat space: 
$$ x=r*cos(\phi) $$ $$ y=r*sin(\phi) $$ $$z=-1/r^2$$
The Christoffel symbols are:
$$\Gamma^{r}_{i,j}=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{12}{r^7+4r} & 0\\ 
0 & -\frac{r^7}{r^6+4}
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\Gamma^{\phi}_{i,j}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{1}{r}\\ 
\frac{1}{r} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
so the equations of motion are:
$$\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial s^2}=\frac{12}{r^7+4r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial s}\frac{\partial r}{\partial s}+\frac{r^7}{r^6+4}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial s}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial s}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial s^2}=-\frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial s}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial s}$$
(I've written the steps, ignore the equals)I took:
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial r}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial s^2}ds$$
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial s^2}ds$$
$$r=r+\frac{\partial r}{\partial s}ds$$
$$\phi=\phi+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial s}ds$$
Here is the program loop:

`vr = vr + (12/(r^7+4*r)*vr^2) *ds + (r^8/(4*r+r^7)*vphi^2) *ds

vphi = vphi + (-2/r*vr*vphi) *ds

r = r + vr*ds

phi = phi + vphi*ds`

where vr is $\frac{\partial r}{\partial s}$ and vphi is $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial s}$ and $ds=0.00001$.
The problem is that if I start the loop with $r_0=0.5$ , $phi_0=0$, $vphi=1$, $vr=0$ 
when the head of the geodesic goes to infinity I get the speed of the geodesic $\sqrt{vr^2+vphi^2}$ to be $0.5$ instead of 1. What am I doing wrong mathematically?

Comment: Geodesics have constant speed, not necessarily unit speed.

Comment: That said, if the initial velocity is $1$ then it should remain so - is the speed really a constant? I could see it beginning as $1$ and then slowly changing due to the errors in the discretization, but it seems very strange that it would immediately jump away from $1$ and then remain constant.

Comment: Christoffels are right; observe that $r=$ const immediately implies that the second derivation of $\phi$ vanishes.  This follows from your first equation of motion.  So $\phi(s)=s$ regarding vphi=1 and phi=0.

Answer (score 1):

That took a long time for me to see the error ... From your second equation of motion it follows that the second derivative of $\phi$ equals $0$, thus $\phi(s)=as+b$.  The first equation then reads
$$
\frac{r^7}{r^6+4}\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial s}\right)^2=0,
$$
that is either $a=0$, so $\phi$ is constant, or $r=0$, which is impossible.  So no geodesic with $r=$ const and vphi $\neq0$ is  possible.  (Cutely your $\sqrt{vr^2+vphi2}=const$ remains true, namely $const=0$ ...)

So what did you mathematically do wrong?  You presumed the existence of an object that doesn't exist.

Michael

Comment: The speed of the geodesic is at first 1 since vr is zero and vphi is one, the speed is oriented in the phi direction. But then when the direction of the geodesic begins to veer towards the r direction vphi starts to tend to zero... but vr instead of tending to one, it tends to the value of the initial r position. For example, if the geodesic starts from $r=0.5$ then vr will tend to 0.5, if $r=0.1$ the  vr will tend to 0.1, if $r=10$ Then vr will tend to 10, etc. I guess that if vphi is 1 when vr is zero the  vr must be one whenever vphi=0. Thanks for the effort you've put. +1 :>

Comment: Not quite: if $r =const$ the geodesic must have velocity $0$, that is, it is constant.  Convince yourself that on a surface of revolution the geodesics with $r=const$ are not constant if the fubction, which gives the shape -- in our case $-1/r^2$ -- has a critical value.